# How can I build c++ program which acts as a wrapper of lua language in a machine without installing lua-dev?

Tags: c++, c, lua

When I build c++ programe which acts as a wrapper of lua language in a machine without installing lua-dev, it prints error message like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: liblua5.1.so.0, needed by ../build/lib/liblua_print.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
../build/lib/liblua_print.so: undefined reference to `luaL_newstate'
../build/lib/liblua_print.so: undefined reference to `luaL_openlibs'
../build/lib/liblua_print.so: undefined reference to `lua_pcall'
../build/lib/liblua_print.so: undefined reference to `luaL_loadfile'
../build/lib/liblua_print.so: undefined reference to `lua_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My build process like this (error emerges at the last line):

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -I../include/ -c ./lua_print.cpp -o ../build/object/lua_print.o                                                                                  
g++ -fPIC -shared -o ../build/lib/liblua_print.so ../build/object/lua_print.o -L../lib/ -llua5.1
g++ -fPIC -shared -I. -c ./main.cpp -o ../build/object/main.o
g++ -o ../build/bin/crnn_demo ../build/object/main.o ../build/lib/liblua_print.so
```

And my program organized as this :

```
demo
  lib
    liblua5.1.so (link to liblua5.1.so.0)
    liblua5.1.so.0 (link to liblua5.1.so.0.0.0)
    liblua5.1.so.0.0.0 (copy from another machine that installs lua-dev)
  src
    main.cpp
    lua_print.c
    lua_print.cpp
  include
    lua.hpp (copy from another machine)
    ..(other lua's header file copied from another machine)
  build (result dir)
    object (store main.o, lua_print.o)
    lib (store liblua_print.so)
    bin (store final result)
```

Comment: `liblua5.1.so.o` I am pretty sure that should be a 0 (zero) at the end and not o

Comment: @Hayt thanks for remind. I hava edited again

Comment: As you have discovered, you need the files in `lua-dev` to compile programs that link with liblua.  Why don't you want to install it?

Comment: @zwol because i hava no permission to install `lua-dev` on the target machine, so i am finding a more portable way

Comment: @JacobWong: You cannot use Lua without *using Lua*.

Comment: Just download the source from lua.org and build Lua yourself. Fastest and simplest.